# JavaScript/JQuery Combo like drop down menu issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, drop-down-menu

I am wondering if someone can tweak my code to get the functionality I am looking for. I am missing something in here. I am almost there. The problem is that when a menu item is selected from the list it is not moved up but duplicated. Then, if I click to drop down this menu again, then I’ll get two the same items in the menu. Ideally, I need the selected menu item to be moved to the top and do not have any duplicated content in the menu. Please take a look at my working prototype on jsfiddle in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vladc77/DAgGP/):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladc77/DAgGP/)

I also am wondering if you can position the text inside menu items to be alight in the middle and left margined to 10px. I tried to make it but this does not go easy I expected.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").css("display", "block");
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DAgGP/3/

for css part you can use text-indent:

```
.dropdown dd ul li a {
   text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It is super great. The only comment is that I need to start the menu from one of the menu item. On drop down, the menu will show only 3 additional menu items. I had 'test' string on top only for placeholder, which I wanted to change to one of the menu item. Is that easy to change? Thank you again.

Comment: @vladc77 you are welcome, yes, it is easy to change: http://jsfiddle.net/DAgGP/5/

Comment: I just noticed that the image is not shown in the top menu from the beginning. It is possible to have it from the start? Thank you again.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it by changing this code line: $(".dropdown dt a span").html($(".dropdown dd ul li a").eq(0).html())

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

### *[demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpQPn/)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     
    var temp = '';
    
    $('.dropdown dt:eq(0)').on('click',function(){
        $('.dropdown dd ul').toggle();
    });
    
    $('dl.dropdown li').on('click',function(){
        $thisA = $('a', this);
        temp = $thisA.text();
        $thisA.closest('li').hide().siblings('li').show();
        $('.dropdown span').text(temp);
        $('.dropdown dd ul').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: @vladc77 glad to be alive and help! ;)